# nodejs - fs.stat isFile() always returns true when executed as daemon/service from systemd

Tags: node.js, linux, daemon, fs, systemd

Usually when executing a nodejs script with an fs.stat on a file that doesn't exist (`config.js`), as expected, it passes the callback an error; However when executing the same script as a deamon with systemd the fs.stat provides no error and `stat.isFile()` returns true.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is this a bug?
Is this a feature?

- OS: Arch linux
- Nodejs: v9.3.0

server.js (the script I mentioned):

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.stat('./config.json', (err, stat) => {
    console.log('err:', err);
    if (err) return;
    console.log('stat:', stat);
    console.log('stat.isFile():', stat.isFile());
});
```

/etc/systemd/system/nat-server.service (systemd file):

```
[Unit]
Description=Network address transaltion server
Documentation=https://github.com/jkeveren/nat-server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=jkeveren
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/jkeveren/mega/code/util/nat-server/server.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Normal (desired) output:

```
err: { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './config.json'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: './config.json' }
```

systemd output (notice the last line):

```
Dec 19 13:49:59 jji-li systemd[1]: Started Network address transaltion server.
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]: err: null
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]: stat: Stats {
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   dev: 2051,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   mode: 33188,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   nlink: 1,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   uid: 0,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   gid: 0,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   rdev: 0,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   blksize: 4096,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   ino: 15,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   size: 67,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   blocks: 8,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   atimeMs: 1513681349595.1235,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   mtimeMs: 1513681349595.1235,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   ctimeMs: 1513681349595.1235,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   birthtimeMs: 1513681349595.1235,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   atime: 2017-12-19T11:02:29.595Z,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   mtime: 2017-12-19T11:02:29.595Z,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   ctime: 2017-12-19T11:02:29.595Z,
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]:   birthtime: 2017-12-19T11:02:29.595Z }
Dec 19 13:50:00 jji-li node[17498]: stat.isFile(): true
```

Comment: Looking at the `time` available in the `stat` structure, I guess the file was indeed there - created recently . Your script could be creating it ?

Comment: @Malice Yea that crossed my mind but that's the entire server.js posted above so there's no purposeful creation and the file still doesn't exist after running. server.js will create the file later on if its not found but that's not implemented yet.

Comment: Do you observe the same effect when you change './config.json' to './nonexistent.json' i.e. a file that has never existed and nothing is (or will be) creating it now (or in the future)? In other words, do you see this behaviour with all files that should not exist or only that specific one?

Comment: @rsp Ah, thank you, it seems to work with nonexistant.json. the daemon output is showing me ENOENT, as expected. So I seem to be having a phantom config.json file then. I'll try a reboot.

Comment: Rebooting did not fix the issue, Still phantom config.json . I also tried renaming the directory that contained config.json and no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `systemd` runs a program it uses `/` as the working directory, which makes perfect sense, it just didn't cross my mind for some reason or another.

This means that when `fs.stat` looks for `./config.json` it looks for `/config.json` which does exist from a previous run of this script when it had a config generator.

The solution is to replace:

```
fs.stat('./config.json', (err, stat) => {
```

with:

```
fs.stat(path.join(__dirname, './config.json'), (err, stat) => {
```

Hopefully this will help anyone (including me) who has the same issue (again) in the future.